# Help: $ |\frac{a+1}{a}- (\frac{xz}{y^2})^k|\leq \frac{1}{b}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation

In the paper [linear forms in the logarithms of real algebraic numbers close to 1](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/ConfMumbaidef.pdf), it is written on page $9$ that

> On other hand, a short calculation yields 
>      $$ \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \left(\frac{xz}{y^2}\right)^k\right|\leq \frac{1}{b}$$

**Image of the page :-**
[image]

Here, 
$$\left(\frac{xz}{y^2}\right)^k= \frac{(a+1)(ab^2+1)}{(ab+1)^2}$$ and $ b \geq 2, a\geq 2^{49},k\geq 50 $ (see page $8, 9$).

So,  how do we prove the following?

$$ \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \frac{(a+1)(ab^2+1)}{(ab+1)^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{b}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, using  $b\ge 2$ and $a\ge 2^{49}$, 
$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \frac{(a+1)(ab^2+1)}{(ab+1)^2}\right|
&=(a+1)\left|\frac{1}{a}- \frac{(ab^2+1)}{(ab+1)^2}\right|
\\\\&=(a+1)\left|\frac{(ab+1)^2-a(ab^2+1)}{a(ab+1)^2}\right|
\\\\&=(a+1)\left|\frac{1+a(2b-1)}{a(ab+1)^2}\right|
\\\\&=(a+1)\cdot \frac{1+a(2b-1)}{a(ab+1)^2}
\end{align}$$

Here, since 
$$ab+1\ge ab$$
we have
$$\frac{1}{ab+1}\color{red}{\le}\frac{1}{ab}$$
Also, we have
$$a+1\le \frac{a^2}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad 1+a(2b-1)\le 2ab$$

Using these gives
$$\left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \frac{(a+1)(ab^2+1)}{(ab+1)^2}\right|
=(a+1)\cdot \frac{1+a(2b-1)}{a(ab+1)^2}\le \frac{a^2}{2}\cdot\frac{2ab}{a(ab)^2}=\frac 1b$$

Comment: When u divide something  with big nunber the amount become smaller, I urge u to  check/revise last paragraph of your answer

Comment: @Mike SQ : The last inequality is true since $ab+1\ge ab$ implies $\frac{1}{ab+1}\color{red}{\le}\frac{1}{ab}$. I've added some explanations in my answer.

Comment: @Mike SQ : I'm going to give another explanation. After having $(a+1)\cdot \frac{1+a(2b-1)}{a}\le\frac{a^2}{2}\cdot \frac{2ab}{a}$, which should be clear, we divide the LHS with *larger* number $(ab+1)^2$ and divide the RHS with *smaller* number $(ab)^2$, so we get our last inequality. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have got $$\left|\frac{a+1}{a}-\frac{(a+1)(ab^2+1)}{(ab+1)^2}\right|=\left|{\frac { \left( a+1 \right)  \left( 2\,ab-a+1 \right) }{a \left( ab+1
 \right) ^{2}}}
\right|$$
I have compute $$\frac{1}{4}-f(a,b)^2=\frac{\left(a^3 b^2-2 a^2 b+2 a^2-4 a
   b+a-2\right) \left(a^3 b^2+6 a^2 b-2 a^2+4 a
   b+a+2\right)}{4 a^2 (a b+1)^4}$$ and this is positive if $$b\geq 2,a\geq 2^{29}$$

Comment: Your inequality is right, defining $$f(a,b)=\left|{\frac { \left( a+1 \right)  \left( 2\,ab-a+1 \right) }{a \left( ab+1
 \right) ^{2}}}
\right|$$ and you must searched for a maximum of $$f(a,b)$$

Comment: ... need a proof !!! :) I could not find one....